# Reading order for Wolverine's history

Tags: marvel, comics, suggested-order, wolverine

I want to learn the history of Wolverine from the beginning.

What comic issues should I read and in what order to understand how he became what he is (*what* he actually is) and he came to the present day?

I would prefer historical event order, but whatever you think is the best to understand the whole story is welcome

Comment: Are you more interested in published order, or historical event order?

Comment: Historical event order preferably, but whatever you think is the best to understand the whole story

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Wolverine's history is so long, rich and convoluted that this could *almost* be seen as a list-question. There are so many stories that help paint the picture of Wolverine that I feel like I could just keep adding more and more stories, but I think this list gives you a good "at least read these" point.

- Wolverine Origin 1-6 (Collected as Wolverine: Origin) - Canon information regarding the circumstances of Wolverine's birth, discovery of his mutant powers and adoption of the name "Logan".
- Marvel Comics Presents 72-84 (Collected as Wolverine Weapon X) - The first attempt at an official origin of Wolverine and his claws. Later stories reveal that some of these memories are false or altered, but this is essential reading.
- Uncanny X-Men 120-121 - Prior to joining the X-Men, Wolverine was a member of the Canadian team Alpha Flight. They haven't forgotten him and demand that he returns to service with them.
- Wolverine 1-4 (Limited Miniseries) - Wolverine vs The Hand. The first real solo story for Wolverine.
- Uncanny X-Men 172-173 - Wolverine's wedding - Wolverine prepares to wed Mariko Yashida but must deal with potential fallout from their union. This was loosely adapted into the film *The Wolverine*.
- Uncanny X-Men 212-213 - Part of the Mutant Massacre storyline. Wolverine looks for survivors and comes across Sabertooth. Often regarded as their best battle.
- Incredible Hulk 340 - Wolverine vs Gray Hulk. For many, this is considered his greatest battle ever.
- Kitty Pryde and Wolverine 1-6 - Wolverine has a tendency to take younger members (particularly females) under his wing and become a parental figure/mentor. Kitty Pryde was the first. This story goes into their relationship.
- Wolverine 1-23 (Collected as Wolverine Classic 1-4) - Wolverine adopts the pseudonym of "Patch" and spends time in Madripoor. He runs into The Silver Samurai,  Jessica Drew (Spider-Woman), Gray Hulk and others. This gives a really good look into Wolverine's mind as a loner.
- Wolverine 48-50 - The Shiva Scenario. Wolverine's memories begin surfacing when he and Jubilee visit an old Weapon X facility. Wolverine learns that some of his memories are false. Elements of this were loosely adapted into the film *X-Men Origins: Wolverine*.
- X-Men Fatal Attractions (collection of 6 X-Men related books) - X-Men #25 specifically. Magneto returns and the X-Men step up to take very drastic measures. This is where the adamantium is ripped from Wolverine's body by Magneto, revealing his bone claws beneath.
- House of M (major crossover series, 8 main issues) - The Scarlet Witch suffers a mental breakdown and creates an alternate world and ends up eradicating all mutant powers. In the fallout, Wolverine regains all of his actual memories. He also learns he has a son, Daken.
- Logan (1-3) - Wolverine has regained his memories. Now he must confront them and tie up loose ends.
- Wolverine: Origins 10-15. Wolverine meets his son Daken
- Wolverine & The X-Men 25-35 - Wolverine's half-brother, Dog Logan, appears in the present, working with The Hellfire Club. There is a really *great* speech by Wolverine about how much he's grown over the years, and what Charles Xavier and the X-Men mean to him.
- The Death of Wolverine (4 issue miniseries + crossover issues) - A virus shuts down Wolverine's healing factor and he confronts the man who gave him his adamantium. Wolverine dies in the ensuing battle.
- Wolverine: Old Man Logan Vol 1-3 - Exists in an alternate continuity (Earth-807128) where the X-Men are all dead, and the US has been overrun by villains. Logan embarks on a road trip on a job to deliver a package. Elements of this were loosely adapted into the film *Logan*.

Comment: Wait... no Wolverine and the X-Men??? (covering Dog)?

Comment: @phantom42 - Excellent list (**Kitty Pryde and Wolverine is the BEST Wolvie story IMHO**) but I would add the [**LOGAN: Path of the Warlord**](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/db/issues/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=5081) one-shot and maybe the [**LOGAN: Shadow Society**](http://www.uncannyxmen.net/db/issues/showquestion.asp?fldAuto=2271).  I also think before the **Wolvie mini** they should read **Uncanny #120-121** and after the **Kitty Pryde & Wolverine** series they should read the first few **Wolverine Classic** TPBs as they cover some excellent adventurers like when he was *Patch* on Madripoor =]

Comment: @DVK I'm a little behind in my reading, Dog only just recently showed up for me. I've added the issues though.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza I added some of those. I'm not familiar with Path of the Warlord or Shadow Society. I'll read up on them later and add them when I can summarize them reasonably.

Comment: Cool. I had been thinking you might also want to add **Original Sin** Wolverine Origins #28-30/X-Men Legacy #217-218/X-Men: Original Sin #1 as well as the **Wolverine Goes to Hell** storyline in Wolverine (4th series) #1-5 and **The Romulus Story Arc** Wolverine: Origins #37-40 not to mention the death of Daken -**Final Execution Saga**- Uncanny X-Force #20-29.